# AMQP consumer loads CPU to 100%

Tags: symfony, rabbitmq, consumer

I have Symfony2 application with [RabbitMQBundle](https://github.com/videlalvaro/RabbitMqBundle) installed. I've setup consumers and producers as it's described in the bundle documentations and everything works correct. But my consumers started with ***./app/console rabbitmq:consumer*** take all available CPU time. Basically consumer does nothing but waiting for a message and output it. If I start demo consumer from [php-amqplib](https://github.com/videlalvaro/php-amqplib) CPU consumption is almost zero. I tried different virsions of Symfony (2.6 and 2.3) but this does not affect CPU load. My server configuration:

1. Debian 7
2. PHP 5.6.4 (also tried 5.4)
3. no database used
4. RabbitMq 3.4.2

Is there any way to reduce CPU consumption? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into a very similar issue and after some debugging realized that I was using an old way of instantiating the connection to rabbitmq.

The new signature of the method is described here: https://github.com/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/blob/master/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php#L136

I was sending in something that looked more like

```
$this->connection = new Connection\AMQPConnection(
    $server->host,
    $server->port,
    $server->user,
    $server->password,
    $server->vhost,
    $server->insist,
    $server->login_method,
    $server->locale,
    $server->connection_timeout,
    $server->read_write_timeout,
    $server->context,
    $server->keepalive,
    $server->heartbeat
);
```

As per a very old definition around somewhere in version 2. https://github.com/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/blob/v2.0.0/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AMQPConnection.php#L31

So your plugin seems to use a new version of the library but not the new way to initiate a connection.

Comment: How does that even happen?